# PHP Execute program (Windows)

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute 1 program. I tried with `exec`, `shell_exec` and `system` but when I click the button, it just keeps loading.

I don't need values returned, I just need program executed.

Here is part of the code I used:

```
exec("start servery/" . $port . "/start.exe");
```

I also tried

```
exec("servery/" . $port . "/start.exe");
```

I'm using PHP 5.5 and the program is coded in AutoIt.

Here is the whole code:

```
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['start'])){
   exec('J:/xampp/htdocs/servery/' . $port . '/start.exe');
   header("Location: ?page=ovladanie");
}
?>
```

Comment: If one of answers provide a solution then mark this answer as accepted. If you delete a content of your question then nobody can use it in the future - please restore your question.

Comment: I have rolled back the question. Please refrain from sabotaging your own post!

Answer (score 0):

In `exec()`, either have the PATH Variable specified, or use absolute path like `C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.exe` OR `exec(dirname(__FILE__) . 'path/to/file/start.exe');`

Comment: Tried it and didnt helped. Its still refreshing.

Comment: See updated answer. If you use `dirname(__FILE__)` this will point absolutely to the folder where the executed file is located in

Comment: @Bannery This code you provided cant work! Your `header()` will get executed without waiting for `exec()` to be executed! 
You'll get loop because the header keeps the Post-Request cause you are redirecting to the same page. Please use a html redirection instead (timeout like 2-3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If your host is Unix based rather than Windows based, it is not likely to work.

Comment: Im using Windows 7.